# Indicate that content shouldn't be indexed... an improved <noscript>

Tags: seo, html

I have a web-based app (not primarily content-based) that relies on some modern browser tech to function.  I want to show a default message in the markup for when the browser isn't running JavaScript or cannot run my code due to lack of compatibility.

How do I prevent search engines from using this content on search results pages?  Is there some way I can indicate in an element that all containing content should be ignored?

```
<div noindex>
  <p>Sorry, but this site requires ...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Google executes JS if it's simple enough, so one idea would be to use `noscript` tags, then write a small piece of JS to remove all the `noscript` tags. I've never tried that, though, so I'm not sure it would work.

Comment: I also want this to display to people, even if they have JavaScript enabled.  That's why `<noscript>` doesn't work.  While `<noscript>` would display for folks with JavaScript completely disabled, that doesn't cover ES6, nor detection for other features.  So, I have this div now which I remove with script... but I want to also indicate that the contents of this div shouldn't be indexed.